# Text Extraction from Skew Images OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, tesseract

I am new to OpenCV and I have seen many solution of text extraction trough OpenCV but none of them solved my problem. I am using visual studio 2013 with tesseract OCR, C++ and OpenCV.

My problem is to extract text from a skewed image. Here is an example image that I want to de-skew and I need to extract the whole text. [image]

Comment: http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-detect-skew-angle/. this is not working for my problem i have seen it already.

Answer (score 2):

You can see this tutorial to detect the skew angles in your images and process them. This tutorial completely illustrates how to solve your problem:

http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-detect-skew-angle/

**Including the jist of the linked tutorial below:**

Implementation with OpenCV

First, let's declare a function compute_skew, it takes a path to an image as input and outputs the detected angle to standard output.
First we load the image and stores its size in a variable, very simple.

```
void compute_skew(const char* filename)
{
   // Load in grayscale.
   cv::Mat src = cv::imread(filename, 0);
   cv::Size size = src.size();
```

In image processing, objects are white and the background is black, we have the opposite, we need to invert the colors of our image:

```
cv::bitwise_not(src, src);
```

And here is the result:

[image]

In order to compute the skew we must find straight lines in the text. In a text line, we have several letters side by side, lines should therefore be formed by finding long lines of white pixels in the image. Here is an example below:

[image]

Of course as characters have an height, we find several lines for each actual line from the text. By fine tuning the parameters used later or by using preprocessing we can decrease the number of lines.

So, how do we find lines in the image ? We use a powerful mathematical tool called the Hough transform. I won't dig into mathematical details, but the main idea of the Hough transform is to use a 2D accumulator in order to count how many times a given line has been found in the image, the whole image is scanned and by a voting system the "best" lines are identified.
We used a more efficient variant of the Standard Hough Transform (SHT) called the Probabilistic Hough Transform (PHT). In OpenCV the PHT is implemented under the name HoughLinesP.

In addition to the standard parameters of the Hough Transform, we have two additional parameters:

minLineLength – The minimum line length. Line segments shorter than that will be rejected. This is a great tool in order to prune out small residual lines.
maxLineGap – The maximum allowed gap between points on the same line to link them.
This could be interesting for a multi-columns text, for example we could choose to not link lines from different text columns.
Back to C++ now, in OpenCV the PHT stores the end points of the line whereas the SHT stores the line in polar coordinates (relative to the origin). We need a vector in order to store all the end points:

```
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> lines;
```

We are ready for the Hough transform now:

```
cv::HoughLinesP(src, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 100, size.width / 2.f, 20);
```

We use a step size of 1 for ρ and π/180 for θ, the threshold (the minimum number of votes) is 100.
minLineLength is width/2, this is not an unreasonable assumption if the text is well isolated.
maxLineGap is 20, it seems a sound value for a gap.

In the remaining of the code we simply calculate the angle between each line and the horizontal line using the atan2 math function and we compute the mean angle of all the lines.
For debugging purposes we also draw all the lines in a new image called disp_lines and we display this image in a new window.

```
    cv::Mat disp_lines(size, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    double angle = 0.;
    unsigned nb_lines = lines.size();
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < nb_lines; ++i)
    {
        cv::line(disp_lines, cv::Point(lines[i][0], lines[i][1]),
                 cv::Point(lines[i][2], lines[i][3]), cv::Scalar(255, 0 ,0));
        angle += atan2((double)lines[i][3] - lines[i][1],
                       (double)lines[i][2] - lines[i][0]);
    }
    angle /= nb_lines; // mean angle, in radians.

    std::cout << "File " << filename << ": " << angle * 180 / CV_PI << std::endl;

    cv::imshow(filename, disp_lines);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    cv::destroyWindow(filename);
}
```

We just need a main function in order to call compute_skew on several images:

```
const char* files[] = { "m8.jpg", "m20.jpg", "p3.jpg", "p16.jpg", "p24.jpg"};

int main()
{
    unsigned nb_files = sizeof(files) / sizeof(const char*);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < nb_files; ++i)
        compute_skew(files[i]);
}
```